# Калькулятор для woocommerce

Tags: javascript, woocommerce

Всем привет
Мне нужно сделать калькулятор как на этом сайте https://mmonster.co/products/WoW-Burning-Crusade-Classic-Gold-Carry он должен работать на woocommerce посоветуйте мб статьи или плагины которые помогут, буду очень благодарен)

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, сайт  https://mmonster.co/ сделан на symfony, vue, webpack и еще 2-х десятках технологий, предназначенных больше для написания сайта, чем для сборки по принципу плагинов, как на вордпрессе.

Во-вторых, не совсем понятно, какой калькулятор вы хотите. По ссылке, что вы дали, навскидку кроме того, что это просто карточка товара с добавлением оного в корзину, ничего сказать нельзя.

Так что:

1. нужно писать с нуля ручками
2. настроить то, что есть в woocommerce
3. описать конкретно, что вы хотите.